# java array sorting

Tags: java, arrays

how to sort an simple array logically (for both string & int) ?

without using Arrays.sort(arr) or any comparators.

Comment: "without using arrays sort method." - whoa, I smell homework.

Comment: You're asking how to do sorting in general? Wikipedia has great articles on this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm see the bottom for a bunch of different algorithms. @Andreas_D my thoughts exactly.

Comment: (you can't sort without comparing...)

Comment: compare but without using any comparators

Comment: @Andreas_D; oh yes you can, radix sort/pigeonhole sort work quite well. Patricia trees are another example for strings, although that's pretty much a special case of radix sort.

Comment: strange limitation - why do you not allow implementing a `Comparator`, it could be used in a custom, flexible sorting algorithm. Otherwise you need an individual sorting algorithms for each and every data type. Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: what does logically mean? Again, I smell homework. In any case the question is very vague. You could ask: what sorting algorithms exists? what are better? where I can find code for?

Comment: @Andreas_D it makes sense if you want to beat that elusive nlogn limit imposed on comparison sorts. Again, check out radix sort.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a nice selection including code examples for the various ways to sort arrays and/or collections: [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Sorting_Algorithms)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Arrays.sort()`. See the API documentation of class `java.util.Arrays`.

Example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

// ...

String[] arr = new String[] { "one", "two", "three" };
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

*edit* - Ok, you've edited your question and added "without using `Arrays.sort()`". Is this homework? Are you supposed to implement your own sorting algorithm? Then just do some research on sorting algorithms and implement one yourself.

Comment: "without using arrays sort method"?

Comment: Thanks roe! It didn't say "without using arrays sort method" when I first answered the question.

Comment: That's why you get the +1 from me. Changing the requirements after receiving some answers is not fair and the penalty for this should *only* go to the questioner ;)

Comment: I didn't downvote, so don't blame me.. :) I hate it that you can edit your question without it showing up in history. Answers ok, but questions..? :P

Answer (score 1):

Write a quicksort or mergesort algorithm. Smells homework, too.

Comment: For anyone obviously not knowing much about sorting this is a bad advice, as both are quite complex and hard to get right.

Answer (score 1):

You can write bubble sort or quick sort or any sorting algorithm yourself

Answer (score 1):

I write my own sorting algorithms in my personal projects without looking at any formal sorting algorithms. It keeps my programming edges sharpend, plus it's interesting to see what you can come up with on your own, compared to the more formal sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

To add a little bit more to their answers above - as you mentioned "sorting logically", you can implement your own Comparator and use [Arrays.sort(array, comparator)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20int,%20int,%20java.util.Comparator)).

Is there a specific reason you want to avoid `Arrays.sort()`?

Answer (score 0):

I have covered sorting algorithms in Java which includes the bubble sort, quick sort and merge sort with comprehensive code and explanations. You may find the code [here](http://tech.bragboy.com/search/label/sorting).

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [Insertion Sort](http://books.google.com/books?id=NLngYyWFl_YC&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=c2+insertionsort&source=bl&ots=BwUvFA7mC9&sig=cmX0iQc20QjPsYr8MwR6nmwuw4U&hl=en&ei=Cg9ETI75EszaOOu2-JoN&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=9&ved=0CCwQ6AEwCDgK#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: ... I really don't think, that *this* reference is useful for the questioner. Insertion Sort may be a simple sorting algorithm but I doubt the rohitroy is studying computer science. (-1)