# sorting a combined array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So my task was to get data for two arrays from the user and then combine those two arrays into a single array and then sort that from least to greatest. I have everything working right except for sorting the combined array and am not sure where to go. What is the best method to sort an array?

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please enter the length of list one");
    int dex1 = input.nextInt();
    int[] list1 = new int [dex1];
    System.out.println("Please enter the values for list one");
    for ( int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
        list1[i] = input.nextInt(); 
    }

    System.out.println("please enter the length of list two");
    int dex2 = input.nextInt();
    int[] list2 = new int [dex2];
    System.out.println("Please enter the values for list two ");
    for ( int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) {
        list2[i] = input.nextInt(); 
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("list1: ");
    printArray(list1);
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.print("list2: ");
    printArray(list2);
    System.out.println("\n");
    int[] list3 = merge(list1, list2); 
    printArray(list3);
 }

 public static int [] merge(int[] list1, int[] list2) {
    int[] list3 = new int[list1.length + list2.length];
    System.arraycopy(list1, 0, list3, 0, list1.length);
    System.arraycopy(list2, 0, list3, 5, list2.length);
     return list3;

    }
 public static void printArray(int arr[]){
    int n = arr.length;
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) { 
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    } 
 }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [java array sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279447/java-array-sorting)

Comment: Look up merge sort and specifically the merge phase of the alogithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort the array in normal accending order use.

```
 Arrays.sort(your_array);
```

and if you want to perform special type sort then use comparator with it.

```
 Arrays.sort(your_array,your_comparator);
```